# retrieve values from a list based on criterea using terraform syntax HCL

Tags: terraform, hcl

I am looking for a terraform expression to retrieve values from a list, i have a list of values

```bash
namespaces = [blue,red,green,ns-blue,ns-green,ns-grey]
```

I would like to retrieve in list format just the values contains "ns", as a result i must get:

```bash
namepsace-filtred = [ns-blue,ns-green,ns-grey]
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a list of strings for a variable `namespace`:

```
variable "namespaces" {
  default = ["blue", "red", "green", "ns-blue", "ns-green", "ns-grey"]
}
```

You can use a [`for`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for) with the [`regex`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/regex) function to check if a string contains a substring. Also, you have to use the [`can`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/can) function to transform the result of the regex to a boolean:

```
locals {
  namepsace_filtred = [for ns in var.namespaces : ns if can(regex("ns", ns))]
}
```

The result of this should be something like this:

```
namepsace_filtred = [
  "ns-blue",
  "ns-green",
  "ns-grey",
]
```